# En Yii2 tengo esté problema: Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException

Tags: yii2

He seguido estos pasos:
chmod -R 777 basic
cd /bsic/web
ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep
sudo chgrp apache ./basic
sudo chown -R apache:apache -R basic

vi /etc/selinux/config
cambiar SELINUX=disabled

Reinicio el apache pero no tengo resultado me siga saliendo el error:
The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/html/basic/web/assets

Comment: intenta poniendoselo directamente a la carpeta `chmod -R 777 basic/web/assets`

Comment: No, no funciona tampoco

Comment: Qué distribución estás usando?

Comment: De linux es fedora 28, php 7.2, mariadb 10.2.18, apache,
de Yii2

Comment: Ya lo resolví gracias, tuve que limpiar caché y funcionó.

Comment: pon tu solución como respuesta por si a alguien le puede servir